# How to use SAGA ShapesToGrid via Processing in a Python plugin?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing

I run these lines in my code:

```
vectorlayer_vector =  ftools_utils.getVectorLayerByName(inputLayer)
Elevation = self.lineAttrib.currentText()
cellSize = int(self.linePix.value())
outPath = self.inputLayerCombo3.text()
output = ftools_utils.getRasterLayerByName(outPath) 

Processing.runAlgorithm("saga:shapestogrid", vectorlayer_vector, Elevation, 0, 0, 4, None, cellSize, output)
```

When I run, I get an tiff image but with nothing. The .aux file is not created and when I try to open the tiff image that I created appears this message:

c:...teste3.tif is not a supported raster data source

So, I guess that the output is wrong. What I have to do to get a correct output? What I missing?

---

I update my code but I have no results yet.

Please see if you can help me.

My code are:

```
inputLayer = self.inputLayerCombo.currentText()
Elevation = str(self.lineAttrib.currentText())
cellSize = int(self.linePix.value())
outPath = self.inputLayerCombo3.text()

Processing.initialize()
Processing.runAlgorithm("saga:shapestogrid", inputLayer, Elevation, 0, 0, 4, "10000.0,14000.0,50000.0,54000.0" , cellSize,outPath)
```

Is a simple code but I don't have any results. I don't know what else to do.
It doesn't create a raster.

Comment: Have you debugged all the parameters in the function to ensure the have the right values?

Have you tried exception handling messages?

Have you run the function in the Processing modeller with the same parameters with succes?

Comment: Yes. I run in processing modeller and I have success. I debugged also and I only have None. I think this algorithm is not running because the result is "Nonetype".

Comment: To run a processing algorithm in python script, I just have to define the fields (input, parameters and output)? Because my output is a path. And the result is nothing. I don´t have to define something more in output?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the file "processing_qgis.log" in the folder ".qgis2/processing", it lists all the processed commands from Processing and their status(success, errors)

If I apply "Shapes to grid", leaving the field "Output extent(xmin, xmax,ymin,ymax)" empty (your **None**):

[image]

the result in "processing_qgis.log"  is:

```
ALGORITHM|Mon Nov 18 2013
16:57:17|processing.runalg("saga:shapestogrid","/Users/testbounds.shp","z",0,0,4,"266390.660211,273780.851652,151462.899477,154949.346806",100,"/Users/Shared/testshapegrid.tif")
```

- testbounds.shp - > your vectorlayer_vector
- "z" -> your Elevation
- "0,0,4" = Methods for multiple values, Method for Lines,Preferred Target Grid Type
- "266390.660211,273780.851652,151462.899477,154949.346806" -> Output extent(xmin, xmax,ymin,ymax) and **None** in your script
- 100 -> cellSize
- shapegrid.tif ->  output

Your None must correspond to the bounding box of the shapefile:

> [Leave blank to use min covering extent]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I try what you said but it gaves me an empty raster again. When I try to open the raster says that the "is not a supported raster data source" and it has 0bytes of size.